# How to display reload image in place statement "Refresh Captcha Image" in Zend

Tags: zend-framework, captcha, recaptcha

When I am adding the below code the reload captcha work fine

In ZEND FORM:

```
$captcha = $this->createElement('captcha', 'captcha', array(
'required' => true,
'captcha' => array(
    'captcha' => 'Image',
    'font' => APPLICATION_PATH . '/../public/fonts/arial.ttf',
    'fontSize' => '24',
    'wordLen' => 5,
    'height' => '50',
    'width' => '150',
    'imgDir' => APPLICATION_PATH.'/../public/captcha',
    'imgUrl' => Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getBaseUrl().'/captcha',
    'dotNoiseLevel' => 50,
    'lineNoiseLevel' => 5,
),
'description' => 'Refresh Captcha Image'

));
```

It worked fine But for captcha I want to use a refresh Image in place of "Refresh Captcha Image" statement.

Comment: can you also post the code where you add the form to your view ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to add an img / div tag as the description ??

```
'description' => '<img src="myimage.png">'

OR

'description' => '<div id="image"></div>'
```

Comment: Sorry, it is not display any image. it showing <img src="myimage.png"> or <div id="image"></div> same in the browser and nothing.

Comment: Even I am already test <div></div> but it is even display the same in the browser so it means in side the "description" any html tag is even display as a text.

Comment: $captcha->addDecorator('Description', array('tag'=>'img','id' => 'refreshcaptcha', 'src'=>Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance()->getBaseUrl().'/captcha'.'/images.jpg', 'style'=>'cursor: pointer; color: #ED1C24',)); It work but there is a problem after refresh the reload images replace with captcha and message still coming.